# Howto stack table row on window resize into one column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a 100% width table with three pictures in a row. I want the table to be responsive and stack the pictures into one column when there is not enough space.

My current problem is that the table elements don't stack into one column if the browser window width is minimized or the page is viewed on a cell phone, thus the picture on the right side become unvisible.

My code looks like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPYyeK

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
  .Table-Upper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Start</a>
      <a href="Foo.html" class="list-group-item">Foo</a>
    </div>         
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <table class="Table-Upper">
      <tr>
        <td><img id="upper-pics" src="p1.jpg" width="200"></td>
        <td><img id="upper-pics" src="p2.png" width="100"></td>
        <td><img id="upper-pics" src="p3.jpg" width="200"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you cannot use table for manage content in column for this feature you need `<div>` with appropriate class.

[try this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwrpwR)

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Start</a>
    <a href="Foo.html" class="list-group-item">Foo</a>
  </div>         
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-4">
  <div class"row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><img id="upper-pics" src="p1.jpg" width="200">  </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img id="upper-pics" src="p2.png" width="100"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" ><img id="upper-pics" src="p3.jpg" width="200"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately the picture row is not transformed to a column

Comment: what size of screen are testing ?

Comment: Its on a Samsung Galaxy S4 so I think the screen size is 1080x1920

Comment: I have update the answer. I hope this could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Finally I wrote it with `<div>` elements according to the three equal columns example at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="row" align="center">
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="p1.jpg" id="upper-pics" width="200"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="p2.png" id="upper-pics" width="100"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><img src="p3.jpg" id="upper-pics" width="200"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```